# ¿Es necesario tener seguridad https para usar firebase en un cliente web?

Tags: php, javascript, firebase, yii, fcm

Hola el problema consiste que esta desarrollado un chat para la comunicación entre una app y un chat web de atención al cliente, creado con firebase usando la api de FCM de firebase, el chat solo me muestra la primera conversación de la lista de conversaciones, al querer abrir una nueva conversación me carga una nueva pagina y en la url me aparece que me abrió una nueva conversación pero en realidad me muestra la misma primera conversación.

Ya he buscado solucionar el problema y tengo dos diferente chats uno que desarrollamos para pruebas que no tiene ningún error y hace exactamente lo que quiero hacer, pero al momento de activar el firebase aparece ese error al revisar la documentación de firebase me dice que esta tecnología solamente sirve para sitios https,quiero saber si no cuento con este certificado no voy a poder solucionar mi problema

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta es que sí es necesario dicho certificado.

Firebase está diseñado para funcionar solo bajo protocolos de transmisión seguros, en este caso el certificado SSL para HTTPS será necesario para comunicarse con los servicios de backend.